# How and where to store plenty of images that are to be displayed in app

Tags: android, image, android-image

I am trying to develop an android app, where I will be required to display a lot of images such as infrastructure, events and so on.

I don't think that storing them in drawable folder is the best option. So what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: save them in firebase storage then access them from there if you have a apk size issue . otherwise just convert them to .WEBP format it will reduce there size  and save them in drawable folder .

Comment: Use firebase cloud storage

Answer (score 1):

If you use vector drawables it shouldn't be a problem if you store them in the drawables folder - they're small and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in assets directory.

Additionally you can convert these images to webp by right-clicking them inside android studio project explorer and clicking convert to WebP.

For Vector assets, you can let them be inside drawable folder.